# MATLAB two for loops for a range and a recurrence equation

Tags: matlab, plot

I have been given a recurrence equation: X(n) = A*X(n-1)/1+B*X(n-1).  I am having trouble  plotting this solution into MATLAB 2014b, which returns a figure which plots multiple curves that range from O:10 on a single graph. This is what I have so far in terms of making a range in the form of y:

```
function questions1 ()
N = 100; %Xn in the form of n
X = zeros (N,1);
X(1) = 0;
A = 2;
B = 1;

for y = 0:10; %this is the range from 0:10 to plot curves
    for n = 2:N;
          X(n) = A*X(n-1)/1+B*X(n-1); %this is the recurrence equation
    end
end

hold on;
plot(X);
hold off;
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

```
X(0)=0
x(1)=a*x(0)/1+b*x(0)=a*0+b*0=0
x(2)=a*x(1)+b*x(1)=a*0+b*0=0
..
∀n, x(n)=0
```

So your recursive equation is quite bad..
And you're replacing x(n) on each y-iteration, here is a fix:

```
function question1()
N = 100; %Xn in the form of n
X = zeros(N,1);
X(1) = 0;
A = 2;
B = 1;
hold on;
for y = 0:10; %this is the range from 0:10 to plot curves
    for n = 2:N;
        X(n) = A*X(n-1)/1+B*X(n-1); %this is the recurrence equation
    end
    plot(X);
end
hold off;
```

Comment: Hi, i tried what you did and it is only plotting on curve instead of multiple curves that range from 0:10. Would I have to change the for loop for y ?

Comment: @python_learner it's plotting one curve because in the second y-loop you're not using the previous values from X, so basically you're calculating the same array in each loop (and printing the same), you can do something like.. if y==1 && n==3: use other value instead X(n-1)